# Update records in a loop in postgresql efficiently

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have a bunch of records that looks like this:

```
[
  CategoryEntity { id: 11, position: 2 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 12, position: 1 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 13, position: 3 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 14, position: 4 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 15, position: 5 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 17, position: 6 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 16, position: 7 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 19, position: 8 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 18, position: 9 },
  CategoryEntity { id: 20, position: 10 }
]
```

These are the values I need to update in the category table. I understand they all need to be done withing a transaction, but I'm not sure that executing multiple `await update`s would be the right way to approach this issue.

What is the right practice here?

P.S.

I'm using typeorm but it allows to throw raw queries so a raw query would be welcome as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> save - Saves all given entities in the database. If entities do not exist in the database then inserts, otherwise updates.

So, you can use [TypeORM's](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api/repository-api) `.save()` method:

```
const entities = [
  { id: 11, position: 2 },
  { id: 12, position: 1 },
  { id: 13, position: 3 },
  { id: 14, position: 4 },
  { id: 15, position: 5 },
  { id: 17, position: 6 },
  { id: 16, position: 7 },
  { id: 19, position: 8 },
  { id: 18, position: 9 },
  { id: 20, position: 10 }
];

categoryRepository.save(entities);
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports inserting multiple values:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-insert.html

```
INSERT INTO category (id, position)
VALUES (11, 2), (12, 1) ...
```

If you'd like to update multiple values, you can do that with `UPDATE ... CASE ... WHEN`

```
update category 
  set position = (
     case when id = 11 then 2
     case when id = 12 then 1
     ...
     else position
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question though. Do I have to make it a transaction or in this case it doesn't make sense?

Comment: if I start a transaction and then end it I will need some conditional to roll it back, right? I'm not sure how to do this then.

Comment: No, it does not work, it does not update. It tries to do insertion but it's not what I need. I thought it's possible to make update in postgresql this way, but it is not.

Comment: Sorry, but your questions says "These are the values I need to insert into the category table". Could you clarify what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to upsert, maybe?

Comment: Yeah there's such a line even though the question itself implies that I need to update. My bad, I will correct it right quick, sorry. Is there an efficient solution on how to update the records that are already in the table.